# Could not find or load main class .net.ssl.keyStore

Tags: java

I try to put federated container using `-Djavax`

When using this command `java -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStore=xyz.jks` i get an error could not find or load main class .net.ssl.keyStore-xyz.jks.

I use java version 1.8.0, is net.ssl class included in this version?

Comment: Are you sure that's the _exact_ command you entered? Not, for example, a space between `javax` and `.net.ssl.keyStore`? Best to copy and paste the exact input and output from the console directly into your question.

Comment: You’re just running `java` and defining a property (and see above; it’s likely the command is being entered incorrectly), you’ll also want to tell it what to run.

Comment: `java -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStore=keystore1.jks`                                                   Error: Could not find or load main class .net.ssl.keyStore=keystore1.jks                                                Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: /net/ssl/keyStore=keystore1/jks                 That's the exact command i used

Answer (score 0):

The command you say you are running is plainly incorrect.  There needs to be a class name after the `-Djavax.net.ssl.keyStore=xyz.jks` option.

For example:

```
java -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStore=xyz.jks com.acme.traps.RoadRunnerTrap
```

to run the `RoadRunnerTrap` application with a different SSL keystore.

However leaving out the class name gives you a different error message.  For example, on Java 17 it says:

```
$ java -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStore=xyz.jks 
Usage: java [options] <mainclass> [args...]
           (to execute a class)
   or  java [options] -jar <jarfile> [args...]
           (to execute a jar file)
   or  java [options] -m <module>[/<mainclass>] [args...]
       java [options] --module <module>[/<mainclass>] [args...]
           (to execute the main class in a module)
   or  java [options] <sourcefile> [args]
           (to execute a single source-file program)

...
```

To get the error message that you reported, you actually need a space after the `-D`.  Like this:

```
$ java -Djavax .net.ssl.keyStore=xyz.jks 
Error: Could not find or load main class .net.ssl.keyStore=xyz.jks
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: /net/ssl/keyStore=xyz/jks
```

So ... it appears that you have made TWO mistakes to get this error message:

1. You left out the class name for the class you want to run
2. You embedded a space in the `-D` option.

---

> is net.ssl class included in this version?

It is not a class. `javax.net.ssl.keyStore` is the name of a property.  You can't "run" it.

If your question had explained what the command you were running was *intended* to do, I could have suggested a *correct* way to do it.